# My ISP is blocking some sites. How do I determine where and how it is blocking it?

Tags: networking, dns

Anonymous account for obvious reasons

Sometime in the last 12 hours, multiple Indian ISP's including mine started blocking well known "adult" and some other sites. I ran some rudimentary diagnostics, however cannot figure out where the block is taking place

When navigating to the site, a 404 error is returned with the below HTML

```
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

All the sites return the same HTML as above

Tried using both Google DNS and ISP DNS, same results

The results of nslookup match those on http://ping.eu/nslookup/

Fiddler shows the 404 error originating from the same IP as the site, and shows the below error

```
15:09:44:7155 Fiddler.Network.ProtocolViolation - [#440] No Connection: close, no Content-Length. No way to tell if the response is complete.
```

tracert works, however on the hop out of India there are 2-3 timeouts

Accessing by IP throws up a cloudflare error saying that direct IP access to the site is not permitted

Comment: I dont know if adding the site names would be appropriate here, let me know if I should add them

Comment: @Arjan You're right.. edited

Comment: "blocking well known "adult" and some other sites"*--can you give some non-adult example?

Comment: @Arjan liveleak.com Its borderline adult hence I was hesitant to give it

Answer (score 0):

I think you investigated all there is to investigate. As `nslookup` and `traceroute` are sort of fine, and as using an IP address in a browser "works" (showing the CloudFlare error, which is not your ISP), just a wild guess:

I assume they are blocking sites when seeing some specific [HTTP `Host` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), or for HTTPS with [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), when seeing the host name [in the SSL handshake](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86723/why-do-https-requests-include-the-host-name-in-clear-text/86727#86727). They probably don't even make the request to the target server then (you might want to see if the response times are very low) and return the 404 HTML right away.

But I guess your real concern is: how to circumvent the block? Then using 3rd party VPNs/proxies including [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) are the only way, I'm afraid. (But I am no expert, luckily.)